# INSERT * in MERGE

Tags: python, sql, pandas, merge

I am trying to automate a data read into SQL. The data supplier recommended using a MERGE update on the PK supplied as per the below:

```
MERGE TargetTable AS trg
   USING SourceData AS src
      ON (trg.[FKCS] = src.[FKCS])
      WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN
            INSERT (Everything)
            VALUES (Everything)

      WHEN MATCHED AND src.Col1 <> trg.Col1
                    OR src.Col2 <> trg.Col2
                    OR src.IsDeleted <> trg.IsDeleted
                    OR src.IsUpdated <> trg.IsUpdated
                    OR src.LastDateUpdated <> trg.LastDateUpdated
         THEN UPDATE SET
                  TargetData.[Column] = SourceData.[Column]
```

I am using a python script to run this process and need to do it for 8 tables with different column names. Is there anyway I can somehow automate this without needing to hard code the column names or should I rather use a pandas approach?

I'd also like to substitute the "Everything" with something like SELECT * FROM SOURCEDATA

Comment: Don't. `SELECT *` is a *bad habit*. There's no column order and your query would break if a column was added or removed. You *must* specify the INSERT columns anyway. Using `SELECT *` would end up inserting data into the wrong columns.  Using `MERGE` can result in problems too, as the SQL standard doesn't require it to be atomic. You can easily run into concurrency issues. This single MERGE is no better than an UPDATE followed by an INSERT and quite a bit more complex too.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks. Sounds like I'd be better off exploring a pandas solution.

Comment: Pandas itself uses SQL, generating the INSERT and SELECT statements on the fly. It's convenient, but it often needs help with column data types.

Comment: I managed to do this in pandas - I don't have a data type issue, as it is only a preliminary step before the ETL process, so I can stick to str and varchar data types

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the columns need to be specified and as I was not prepared to go that route, I opted for a pandas approach.

Pandas turned out to be an elegant solution and I managed to achieve the goal using a left merge and keeping only "left_only" records.